# mysql order por dia de la semana

Tags: mysql, date

Hola amigos me podrían ayudar, quisiera hacer una consulta a una bd en mysql para ordenar los registros por el día de la semana en que esta actualmente

Tengo estos registros:

```
+---------+----------+
| id_cron | day_week |
+---------+----------+
|     126 |        2 |
|     131 |        3 |
|     136 |        4 |
|       1 |        0 |
|       2 |        1 |
|      51 |        5 |
|       3 |        6 |
|      61 |        0 |
|      76 |        0 |
|      36 |        5 |
|      41 |        6 |
|       4 |        0 |
|       5 |        1 |
|       6 |        2 |
|       7 |        4 |
|       8 |        3 |
|       9 |        6 |
|      10 |        0 |
|     141 |        3 |
|      11 |        5 |
|      12 |        6 |
|      13 |        0 |
|      46 |        3 |
|      14 |        4 |
|      15 |        6 |
|      16 |        0 |
|      17 |        5 |
|      18 |        6 |
|      66 |        2 |
|      71 |        3 |
|      19 |        0 |
|      20 |        5 |
|      21 |        6 |
|      96 |        3 |
|      91 |        4 |
|     101 |        2 |
|     106 |        5 |
|     111 |        6 |
|      86 |        2 |
|      81 |        5 |
|     121 |        2 |
|     116 |        4 |
|      31 |        0 |
|      22 |        2 |
|      23 |        3 |
|      24 |        0 |
|      25 |        5 |
|      26 |        6 |
+---------+----------+
```

Donde en la columna `day_week`
`2` es `Martes`, `3` es `Miercoles`, `4` es `Jueves` etc

y quiera ordenarlos por el numero de día, empezando por el día en el que nos encontramos.
Ejemplo:
Hoy `2017-09-21` es `4` deberian quedar en el orden `4,5,6,0,1,2,3` asi:

```
+---------+----------+
| id_cron | day_week |
+---------+----------+
|       7 |        4 |
|     136 |        4 |
|     116 |        4 |
|      91 |        4 |
|      14 |        4 |
|      51 |        5 |
|      20 |        5 |
|      11 |        5 |
|      36 |        5 |
|      25 |        5 |
|      81 |        5 |
|     106 |        5 |
|      17 |        5 |
|      26 |        6 |
|      41 |        6 |
|     111 |        6 |
|      21 |        6 |
|      18 |        6 |
|      15 |        6 |
|       3 |        6 |
|      12 |        6 |
|       9 |        6 |
|      16 |        0 |
|       4 |        0 |
|      76 |        0 |
|      61 |        0 |
|      19 |        0 |
|      31 |        0 |
|      13 |        0 |
|       1 |        0 |
|      24 |        0 |
|      10 |        0 |
|       5 |        1 |
|       2 |        1 |
|     126 |        2 |
|       6 |        2 |
|     121 |        2 |
|      66 |        2 |
|      22 |        2 |
|     101 |        2 |
|      86 |        2 |
|     131 |        3 |
|      96 |        3 |
|      71 |        3 |
|      46 |        3 |
|       8 |        3 |
|      23 |        3 |
|     141 |        3 |
+---------+----------+
```

y el dia de mañana si se ejecuta la consulta `2017-09-22` es `5` deberían quedar en el orden `5,6,0,1,2,3,4`

estuve intentando con la funcion `WEEKDAY(NOW())+1` pero no se como aplicarla correctamente

muchas gracias,

saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una solución parecida a la @WillamsMorales , sólo que generalmente los días de semana empiezan a contarse el Domingo, por tanto, debes sumar `1` a la condición del `WHEN`:

```
SELECT id_cron,day_week FROM cron_20170921
ORDER BY 
CASE 
   WHEN day_week - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+1 < 0 
       THEN day_week + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
   ELSE
      day_week - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
   END;
```

---

### Código de prueba

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/BAB11212)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cron_20170921 
(
    id_cron INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    day_week INT
)ENGINE=INNODB;




INSERT INTO cron_20170921 (id_cron,day_week)
    VALUES 
    (1,1),
    (2,1),
    (3,1),
    (4,2),
    (5,3),
    (6,4),
    (7,5),
    (8,5),
    (9,5),
    (10,6),
    (11,7),
    (12,7),
    (13,1),
    (14,2),
    (15,3),
    (16,4),
    (17,5)
;



SELECT id_cron,day_week FROM cron_20170921
ORDER BY 
CASE 
   WHEN day_week - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+1 < 0 
       THEN day_week + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
   ELSE
      day_week - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
   END;
```

### Resultado

```
id_cron     day_week
6            4
16           4
7            5
8            5
9            5
17           5
10           6
11           7
12           7
1            1
2            1
3            1
13           1
4            2
14           2
5            3
15           3
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Intenta restar/sumar el índice del día de la semana al valor de la columna 'day_week', por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
ORDER BY 
CASE 
   WHEN day_week - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) < 0 THEN 
      day_week + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
   ELSE
      day_week - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando el formato

D=0 L=1 M=2 M=3 J=4 V=5 S=6

seria con:

```
CASE 
   WHEN day_week - DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%w") < 0  THEN day_week+ DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%w")
   ELSE day_week- DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%w")
END
```

esto es en el caso de que el domingo cuenta como dia 0

Comment: Por favor deja la edición al código es para mejorar la presentación y legibilidad